# Numpy convert from binary string to array of floats

Tags: python, mysql, arrays, numpy

I have a feature vector of length 16 stored in mysql as a BLOB and I'm fetching that BLOB in python. It is fetched as a binary string. I'm currently converting it to a array first using:

```
list(map(lambda x: list(map(float, x['encoded_vals'].split(b','))), 
    visual_features))
```

My dict looks something like this:

```
{img_id: 1, encoded_vals: b'0.99451257448,0.8541256468...'} # Till 16 values
```

Is there a way to convert this string to numpy array without using `list(map)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
import numpy as np
np.fromstring(text, sep=',')
```

There is no need to split it by `b','` you can provide it through `sep`. It works as it is with bytes, but to be more precise, you should use `text.decode('ascii')`.